# Rails ActionMailer TSL plugin - Sender email problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, actionmailer

I use ActionMailer with the action_mailer_optional_tls plugin to send mails via Gmail.

Here is my setup:

```
class InstantMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  layout "email"  

  def support(ticket)
    @recipients  = "support@domain.com"
    @from        = ticket.email #this is the user's email
    @subject     = "[#{ticket.category}] #{ticket.subject}"
    @sent_on     = Time.now
    @body[:ticket] = ticket
    content_type "text/html"
  end

end
```

Environment:

```
# Mailer Settings
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :tls => true,
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => "587",
  :domain => "domain.com",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => "account@domain.com",
  :password => "***"
}
```

This works fine when I send mail from my server to a user.

However, when a user fills in a contact form, the **from** field is still account@domain.com, and not the user's email. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gmail doesnt allow to relay mails with mailadresses other than the registered...

Answer (score 1):

I changed delivery method to :sendmail and it started to work for me :-)

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
```